# Kafka Connect REST API "cross domain" exception invoking from $.ajax({...})

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, cors, apache-kafka

I have v2.0.1 of the Confluent Data Platform installed and have the Kafka Connect service up and running. While trying to issue REST-calls from a Backbone.js framework I get CORS-exceptions (cross domain exceptions). I do not rely on the Backbone sync API as I use ordinary jquery AJAX calls ($.ajax) against Kafka Connect. A call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://<host>:8083/connectors',
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
        Messenger.trigger('...', data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        Messenger.trigger('...', thrownError);
    }
})
```

results in CORS-exceptions. I've tried dataType: 'jsonp' and then I get a 200 response code BUT the error function is still invoked. The application is a Javascript app running 100% in the browser and is served by nginx web-server. Everything is running on the same machine - the only part that makes the calls "cross domain" is the port numbers: connect 8083 and the app port 80.

NOTE: if I issue the GET from, say, Iceweasel, in the form 'http://localhost:8083' I get a "proper" response and doing "exactly the same using" AJAX results in the following response:

```
http://localhost:8083/connectors

GET /connectors HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8083
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Iceweasel/38.2.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/index.htm
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 08:38:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 30
Server: Jetty(9.2.12.v20150709)
```

However, error function is triggered NOT the success. Whats interesting is that `Content-length` is `30` which is the amount of characters available in the resulting JSON-array `[<string1>, <string2>]`.

Answer (score 2):

For a more complete answer, this has been added in Kafka 0.10.0.0 and Confluent Platform 3.0.0. To allow cross origin requests to the Kafka Connect REST API add:

```
access.control.allow.origin=* # allows requests from any domain
access.control.allow.methods=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE # Defaults to GET,POST,HEAD
```

to your worker configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved in CDP v3.0.0 specifying settings in the Kafka Connect property file.